# How do I use JsHint to display errors on Chrome's dev console?

Tags: jshint

I need to integrate JsHint ( http://www.jshint.com/ ) to print errors on Chrome's dev tools console (F12 key) as if I used console.log.

I downloaded jshint.js and added as external js to my html page.

what's next?

Comment: Print errors when? On page load? Errors from what? All other JS on the page?

Comment: all js errors/warning (another js file is included to load content dynamically). This is why I noticed that Chrome doesn't show the same errors as JsHint

Comment: JSHint exposes a global `JSHINT` function which you need to call with a string of code (plus an optional settings object). So you'll need to somehow get a string of all the JS that loads on your page. But why are you trying to do this? Why not integrate JSHint into your build process?

Comment: could provide an example of "integrating" it, please?

Comment: Look at tools like Grunt or Gulp. There are JSHint plugins available for both of those.